# Task Manager Like App using Java Swing

Tags: swing, taskmanager

I want to how know how to set about writing a monitoring app such as Windows task manager using Java Swing. The main feature I am concerned with is the grid with a graph which get drawn with time. What are the features that I need to accomplish this? (e.g.: Java2D etc).

Answer (score 1):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) can handle the graphing, as shown in the demo, but you'll have to use [ProcessBuilder](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to query the host operating system for its notion of task.

Addendum: For an example, see the *Memory Usage* tab of the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp).

Comment: I am mainly concerned about the UI aspect the app. I am not sure whether JFreeChart is capable of rendering graphs which gets drawn in realtime (for example as the windows task manager CPU usage graph - I mean like an animation)

Comment: I've added a link to the relevant demo.